# Highlighting rows where a cell contains a name from a list of names

Tags: excel, vba

How would I go about highlighting rows which contain a cell that contains a name from a list of names which I can specify?

I assume this is best done by a macro, but not sure where to start.

Comment: yes but this would be difficult considering that I might have a list of 20 names, and it would be very tedious to create a filter for every one

Comment: Where do you want to store your list ? inside the code or in a excel worksheet ?

Comment: inside the excel worksheet would be best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in a module

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ApplyConditionalFormattingsFromAList()
    '
    ' this code create multiple conditional formattings on current selected cells
    ' using a list of conditions along with its formattings defined in another worksheet.
    ' to use, just select the range and then run this code
    '

    Dim iRng        As Range
    Dim ApplyToRng  As Range
    Dim wsCondition As Worksheet

    ' determine the worksheet that define the conditions and formattings
    ' to do this, create a blank worksheet and name it "Names",
    ' then in the worksheet,
    ' column A of the worksheet should contain the names to highlight, start at [A1]
    ' column B of the worksheet should be filled with the highlight color to apply, working in pair with column A
    Set wsCondition = Worksheets("Names")

    ' i make the Macro to apply to current selection.
    ' i made it this way so that you can reuse this code on different sheets multiple times
    ' anyway, you can change this to apply to a fixed range, which can then be turned into automatic running code.
    ' e.g. Set ApplyToRng = Columns("B")
    Set ApplyToRng = Selection

    ' clear the conditional formattings of current selection. otherwise the list of conditional formatting will keep growing.
    ApplyToRng.FormatConditions.Delete

    ' add the conditions
    For Each iRng In wsCondition.Range([A1].Address, wsCondition.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        ApplyToRng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=iRng.Value, TextOperator:=XlContainsOperator.xlContains
        ApplyToRng.FormatConditions(ApplyToRng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        ApplyToRng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = iRng.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
        ApplyToRng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Next iRng
End Sub
```

The worksheet "Names" would look like this

[image: Preview of the Names sheet]

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as a macro.

Begin with the first sheet. 
Find the last used column and the last used row on that sheet.
Use these figures to iterate through each cell in each row.
For each cell you iterate through you need to go to the list and iterate through each item in the list. Compare the cell value and the list value, if they are the same then highlight the row and go the next row.

I hope that helps.