# Copy cell color, hightlight row using dropdown list

Tags: excel, colors, cell

I have a dynamic table that tracks all projects each employee is assigned.  The cells in Col. A use data validation and dropdown list of Client Names (source table is on sheet2).  When a user adds a new row/record and selects a Client from the dropdown, I want to highlight that entire row to match the same color as the client name cell from the source table on sheet2. So basically, each row in the table will be color grouped by Client.

I know this could easily be done with conditional formatting, my problem is if a user needs to add a NEW client name, it is added to the source table and given a color code. So the conditional formatting wouldn't work after a new client name has been added.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: I did something similar with a calendar sheet that pulled tasks from a table.  I put the task colour in the task table as a name "red", "blue", "green" etc.  If you do this on your client list and use a vlookup to pull colour into a hidden column for conditional formatting that matches that on the client list.  You would have create a predefined list of colours and maybe add dark-red, light-blue etc.

Comment: I've applied the solution posted by Rosetta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917327/highlighting-rows-where-a-cell-contains-a-name-from-a-list-of-names/50221192#50221192) however only the first column of my table highlights, the rest of the row remains with no color. My table starts with the headers at A5 and currently has 26 columns and new rows are added each day. Any ideas what I may be missing to highlight the remaining row?